# What's the shortcut to hide windows in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and the shortcut to hide window which was super + D isn't working anymore. What's the shortcut to hide windows in Ubuntu 20.04 please?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the shortcut was disabled by default after the upgrade. I had to add it manually.Go to shortcuts on Ubuntu (Just tap shortcut in the search bar) and then add a shortcut to hide all normal windows (Check the picture):

[image]